# Consider adding android:paddingStart="25dp" to better support right-to-left layouts Error

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, adt

I recently downloaded a new `ADT`. Every time after saving my projects ,it shows the following `XML` error. But the same goes away when I clean it. Is there a permanent solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

```
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectquantityprompt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:text="Select Quantity"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp" //error at this line
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"

        />
```

Multiple annotations found at this line:

```
- Consider adding android:paddingStart="25dp" to better support right-to-left layouts
- When you define %1$s you should probably also define %2$s for right-to-left
```

Comment: Please show the xml file for this message

Comment: Can you try "paddingStart" instead?!

Comment: And paddingRight for RTL, which it's probably trying to tell you?

Comment: Same here. And for me it is not just warnings, but errors! So I can't compile my code without cleaning it first, to get rid of these "errors". And it annoys me, because every build after a cleaning take ages to finish!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

android:paddingStart is newly introduced tag in android 4.2 onwards.

Now RTL means right-to-left layouts which are used in RTL languages like arabic.

So while developing layout you can add same value to paddingStart as padding left. So that when android render RTL layout it will consider paddingStart.

- If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2 (the app's
  targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 17 or higher), then you should
  use “start” and “end” instead of “left” and “right”. For example,
  android:paddingLeft should become android:paddingStart.
- If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2
  (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
  should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
  example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Ref Links: [RTL Layout Support](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL)

[Developer Blog: Native RTL support in Android 4.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to change the severity of that error go to "Lint Error Checking" at Preferences and change "RtlSymmetry" to "Warning" instead "Error".

Answer (score 2):

Just add android:paddingRight="0dp" along with android:paddingLeft="25dp", error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from *sreenu* solved my issue. But if you target higher APIs you should also add paddingEnd, as in the following example:

```
android:paddingLeft="25dp"
android:paddingStart="25dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```