# How can I move the text in a text view like 10dp to the right?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, cursor

I want to move the text like 10dp to the right, not the TextView but the written text + the cursor.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

[The "Hallo" is too near the border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fwH8.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `android:paddingStart =10dp` or `android:paddingLeft =10dp` to this Textview in your layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:text="Hello!"/>
```

For detail explaination about the difference refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132076/consider-adding-androidpaddingstart-25dp-to-better-support-right-to-left-layo)

Answer (score 1):

Add some padding to the start of the TextView!

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:text="done!"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Padding attribute is used to define the alignment offset inside any element** in android (in your case TextView) while margin is used in case of defining the offset around (or you may call outside) the elements.

So in your case you need

> `android:paddingStart="10dp"`

also you may use

> `android:paddingRight="10dp"`

but this has issues with right-to-left aligned devices. So its a *good habbit* to use ***paddingStart* and *paddingEnd* instead of using *paddingLeft* and *paddingRight***.

Also you may find all the extra useful details about attributes of views in android [HERE(Click Me)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).